# Using an image as an option inside a form with a value

Tags: javascript, php, css, forms, variables

This script was made by my friend, but he is unavailable at the time being to go to for some help, so I'd see if I could get some here. I know only of HTML + CSS

Let me lay out a bit of the code I have.

```
$prod = $_POST['prod'];
header("Location: inc/paypal.php?username=". $username ."&prod=". $prod);
```

further down the page

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['username']; ?>" name="username" disabled>
<form method="post">
 <select name="prod">
  <option value="1">Product 1 - $1.00</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2 - $19.99</option>
  <option value="3">Product 3 - $29.99</option>
  <option value="4">Product 4 - $39.99</option>
  <option value="5">Product 5 - $49.99</option>                  
 </select>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Pay Via PayPal" />
```

Instead of using a dropdown, how can I use an image as an option to select, for instance:

```
<div id="img_display">
 <img src="img/product-1.png" value="1">
 <img src="img/product-2.png" value="2">
 <img src="img/product-3.png" value="3">
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to select an image and get the value and forward it to the **`$prod`** variable.

I have had a look around, and found things such as this
http://jsfiddle.net/9rFKB/

But without a decent knowledge of JavaScript or PHP, I'm struggling badly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="prod"> 
    <div id="thumbs">
        <!-- Dynamically created thumbnails start -->
        <img id="pic-1" src="url">
        <img id="pic-2" src="url">
        <img id="pic-3" src="url">
        <!-- Dynamically created thumbnails end -->
    </div>
</form>
```

js:

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    // Clear formatting
    $('#thumbs img').removeClass('border-highlight');

    // Highlight with coloured border
    $this.addClass('border-highlight');

    // Changes the value of the form field "prod" to the value of img.id
    $('[name="prod"]').val( $this.attr('id').substring($this.attr('id').lastIndexOf('-')+1) 

});
```

fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9rFKB/42/)

explanation:
js/jquery catches the `click` on all `img` in `#thumbs`

then removes all highlight effects and adds to the specific one,

then it takes the image `$this` and gets it `id` value, it splits it at the `-` symbol and takes the scondpart (the value) and sets the value of `<input type="hidden" name="prod">` to it.

you dont have to change any php, since `<input type="hidden" name="prod">` sends to `$_POST['prod']` the `name` attribute does the trick

if you use the fiddle version, just remove the alert line... its just for debug reasons since js doesn't provide proper debug mechanisms

Comment: could you make a fiddle and demonstrate please?

Comment: Ah, I see, but how do I forward the value of the `ID` to the variable `$prod` in `$prod = $_POST['prod'];` ?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="prod">` the name parameter links to `$_POST['prod']`

Comment: Brilliant explanation.

Comment: i used what she found and adapted it... ofc your solution is more simple ;)

Comment: Sorry if I were rude.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" name="prod" id="prod">
<div id="img_display" onclick="document.getElementById('prod').value=event.target.name">
 <img src="1.jpg" name="1">
 <img src="1.jpg" name="2">
 <img src="1.jpg" name="3">
</div>
```

N.B. `img` element doesn't have any property `value`. Hence need to use `id` or `name`.

at the server side after the form is submitted you can fetch the value of `prod` as follows-

```
$prod=$_REQUEST['prod'];
```